# Upgrading - Issues finding "workspacesclient/unknown"

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, upgrade, updates

I am having an issue finding where I can update "workspacesclient."

I do not have much information except for the following code (below).

Does anyone know where I can find more information about these packages?

Thank you for your time and assistance.

```
johndoe@system76-pc:~$ sudo apt install update
[sudo] password for johndoe: 
....
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

johndoe@system76-pc:~$ do-release-upgrade -c
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
New release '22.04.1 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

johndoe@system76-pc:~$ sudo apt list --upgradable -a
Listing... Done
workspacesclient/unknown 4.4.0.1997 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.2.0.1665]
workspacesclient/now 4.2.0.1665 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 4.4.0.1997]
```

Here is my OS information:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. `sudo apt install update` is a wrong command. How is `do-release-upgrade -c` related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get information about `workspacesclient` by running

```
apt policy workspacesclient
```

It will show what versions are available and from where.